# How can I put another content under each row in my table?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I Googled a lot but I can't find something for my case. I have a Bootstrap table where I want on click on my rows to show additional info for the main row.

I can't find a way to do this.

I have this code:

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And if I try this:

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <div class="additionl-info">
        <p>Some additional info for the first row...</p>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then my table is broken.

How can I achieve this - on click show additional info for each of my rows?

Comment: Where do you want to position this info? You can't have a div inside a table row: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#technical_summary _"**Permitted content**  Zero or more <td> and/or <th> elements; script-supporting elements (<script> and <template>) are also allowed"_

Comment: additional info div needs to be wrapped inside a <td>.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some [research, search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=bootstrap+show+more+click+site:stackoverflow.com); if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

Add another `<tr>` *after* the current one with a `colspan` which spans all columns and then put another `<td>` with a `<table>` therein.

```
<tr>
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>col2</td>
    <td>col3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <table>...</table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>col2</td>
    <td>col3</td>
</tr>
```

The new table will then appear between the rows.

Comment: The question is _"How can i put another content under each row in my table?"_ I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Add another <tr> after the current one with a colspan which spans all columns and then put another <td> with a <table> therein.

Comment: You should add it to your answer and not comment it.

Comment: Or just put the div content in a td in a new row

Comment: Edited my current answer. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I don't understand the `table` inside the cell. Why is it necessary or even helpful?

Comment: @MarianSerafimov thanks for your reply.But how can i open it onClick ? is there any bootstrap solution for this ?